# Negative number of stock after order many products

Tags: ubercart

I have a website made using Drupal 7 and Ubercart 3.6, and with the `uc_stock` module.

If client is adding to cart product qty more, then set in stock level that is doesn't generate any errors or notices. And stock level is decrementing to negative number, see screenshot:

[image]

Is it possible to disable Negative number of stock level?

Answer (score 0):

Solution of this problem is [Ubercart Out of stock Notification](https://www.drupal.org/project/uc_out_of_stock) module.